# Jquery Validate Error on IE8-10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

I have a checkout page in my e-commerce with jquery validate, in firefox/chrome it works correctly but in internet explorer 8 to 10, I receive the following error:

"object doesn't support this property or method jquery validate"

I have tried older/newer version of validate and jquery, jquery 1.10, 2.0, in 2.0 it does work with IE9 and 10, but we need support to IE8 and jquery 2.0x doesn't support anymore. And yes, I am instantiating correctly the validate.js but simply doesn't work!

Locally it works when I refresh the page, but when I navigate to the link I receive the error, it's completely insane!

Here my code:

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.moip.com.br/transparente/MoipWidget-v2.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.jqzoom-core.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.meio.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.validate.1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.validate.additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.popupWindow.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/jquery/jquery.colorbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.0.24/client/public/template/site/default/javascript/tools/tools.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#identificacao').validate({ // I receive the error in this line
        rules: {
            email:"required",
            senha:"required"
        },
        messages: {
            email:"Por favor, entre com seu e-mail.",
            senha:"Insira sua senha."
        }
    });
```

This was my last try, I tried version 1.7 with validate 1.8 (that worked in another e-commerce), and already tried last version of both, still get the error, I have no clue what happens, anyone had the same error?

I'm using this plugin of validate:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Can you provide the url for the validate plugin that you are using? There are a lot of jQuery Validate plugins out there.

Comment: This: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *`object doesn't support this property or method jquery validate`*

and

> *"Locally it works when I refresh the page, but when I navigate to the link I receive the error, it's completely insane!"*

Yes it's insane... it's Internet Explorer and it doesn't work reliably with `$(window).load()`.  What you describe about refreshing the page is a symptom of this common issue.

See:  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

> - **It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser**
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - **Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache**

Try this instead...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // fires on DOM ready event

    $('#identificacao').validate({ 
        // your rules, options, etc.
    });

});
```

See [jQuery DOM ready event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

---

If you still need the `$(window).load()` event for some other reason, it's perfectly acceptable to place it inside of the DOM ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // <- fires when DOM is ready 

    $(window).load(function() { // <- supposed to fire when all assets have loaded
        ....
    });

});
```

Comment: Amazing, I solved copying files from another project that was working, but I never thought that this ready/load event could give me so much problem, and this other project there was document.ready instead of window.load, so probably was this what solved my problem, I will test again someday! Thanks a lot for information!

Comment: @RafaelMoni, you're welcome.  You must be new to jQuery.  In nearly all cases, your jQuery code is enclosed in a DOM Ready handler.